# Binary Search Logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I was trying to do a binary search algorithm, but I faced myself with a logic problem and I don't understand why that doesn't work...

```
var binarySearch = function(list, num) {
  var low = 0, high = list.length - 1, mid = Math.floor((high - low) / 2);
  while(mid != num) {
    if(num > list[mid]) {
      low = mid;
      mid = Math.floor((high - low) / 2);
    } else {
      high = mid;
      mid = Math.floor((high - low) / 2);
    }
  }
  return mid;
}

var arr = [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 43, 55]
binarySearch(arr, 3);
```

This piece of code is returning 3 fine, but if I put a number like 43, it simply doesn't return anything...

Comment: You need to be wary of the difference between `x` and `list[x]`, where the former is an index ranged from 0 to 7 in this case, while the latter is an array element from 1 to 55. `mid` is an index, `num` isn't, yet you're directly comparing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issues are:

1. Your condition in your while loop. `mid` is an index in your array, not an element. You can use `list[mid]` to get the element at your mid point.
2. You are setting `low` and `hight` to `mid`. But you don't need to re-check these (are you're already checking the `mid` position in your while loop). You can use `mid+1` or `mid-1` instead.
3. Your recalculation of the midpoint is not correct. You want to get the average between the high and low using `Math.floor((high + low) / 2);` instead (note the `+`).
4. Currently your `while` loop only stops once it finds a match. You need to also stop it once you've exhausted all possibilities. This can be done using an additional check to check that the low pointer hasn't passed the hight pointer.
5. You then need to return a `-1` if you can't find the element. This can be done by checking if your `low` and `high` pointers.

```js
var binarySearch = function(list, num) {
  var low = 0, high = list.length - 1, mid = Math.floor((high + low) / 2);
  while(list[mid] != num && low <= high) {
    if(num > list[mid]) {
      low = mid+1;
      mid = Math.floor((high + low) / 2);
    } else {
      high = mid-1;
      mid = Math.floor((high + low) / 2);
    }
  }
  
  return low <= mid ? mid : -1;
}

var arr = [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 43, 55]
console.log(binarySearch(arr, 55));
```

You can simplify your code a little, by performing the equality check in your while loop, and moving the calculation of the `mid`:

```js
var binarySearch = function(list, num) {
  var low = 0, high = list.length - 1;
  while(low <= high) {
    var mid = Math.floor((high + low) / 2);
    if(list[mid] === num)
      return mid;
      
    if(num > list[mid])
      low = mid+1;
    else
      high = mid-1;
  }
  
  return -1;
}

var arr = [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 43, 55]
console.log(binarySearch(arr, 55));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple implementation of binary search in JavaScript:

```js
function binarySearch(arr, x, start, end) {
  if (start > end) {
    return false;
  }
  let mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
  if (arr[mid] == x) {
    return true;
  } else if (arr[mid] > x) {
    return binarySearch(arr, x, start, mid - 1);
  } else {
    return binarySearch(arr, x, mid + 1, end);
  }
}
let arr = [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 43, 55]
let x = 43;
if (binarySearch(arr, x, 0, arr.length - 1)) {
  console.log(x + ' found');
} else {
  console.log(x + ' NOT found');
}
```